# Do Javascript onclick functions override if statements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am simply trying to load a function once a button is clicked but depending on a value it will call a different method and do different things.

I know that the value is set to "set" however it still goes into the if statement and commits the removeAttribute method.

```
if (change == "set"){
            document.getElementById('close').setAttribute("data-dismiss", "modal");
            $('#\\#myModal').modal({ keyboard: false, backdrop: 'static' });
            $('#\\#myModal').modal('show');
            createPicker();
            }
            else if (change == "search"){
                document.getElementById('close').onclick = function(){
                    document.getElementById('close').removeAttribute("data-dismiss");
                    hideFields();
                }
            }
```

If anyone knows how to stop it from going into that else statement when the values don't match it would be much appreciated.

Comment: If `change` really is equal to the string `"set"` then the `else` will not be executed.

Comment: Need to see more. Really need to see how change is being set to determine if it is what you think it is. Try console logging it before the if statement to check it.

Comment: Do you realize that once you attach the event, it will always be attached until you remove it?

Comment: I can screenshot the fact that it is indeed "set". I know because it's shows the value in the chrome debugger. This is why I am so confused

Comment: @Pointy You will need the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) to support your fact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is you already set the `onclick` once, what you need to do is clear the `onclick` even in `set` condition.

```
if (change == "set"){
```

> ```
>        document.getElementById('close').removeEventListener("onclick");
> ```

```
        document.getElementById('close').setAttribute("data-dismiss", "modal");
        $('#\\#myModal').modal({ keyboard: false, backdrop: 'static' });
        $('#\\#myModal').modal('show');
        createPicker();
        }
        else if (change == "search"){
            document.getElementById('close').onclick = function(){
                document.getElementById('close').removeAttribute("data-dismiss");
                hideFields();
            }
        }
```